# <A HREF=javascript:printDoc()>*Link</A> Does not call its javascript function in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Need your help on this.

```html
<A HREF=javascript:printDoc()>Link</A>
```

```js
function printDoc()
{
    window.print();
}
```

I am using a hyperlink to call a JavaScript function that prints the page. It works perfectly on Chrome, but not on Internet Explorer.

What can be the possible solution?

Comment: Why isn't the script inside a <script> tag?

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Try using this: `javascript:void(document.execCommand('print')||print())` or if not in a link, just this: `document.execCommand('print')||print()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of function calls is deprecated. Probably use

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="printDoc()">Link</a>
```

Comment: `void` needs an argument, so you should pass in `void(0)` or something. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Answer (score 1):

Inline javascript in general should be avoided, you'd be better of with something like

```
<a href="" id="someButton">Link</a>


var link = document.getElementById('someButton');
link.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    printDoc();
});
```

I've put in a call to `preventDefault()` there but realistically if your using a `<a>` tag for something that isn't a link you should consider a `button` or `span`

Comment: To be fair: When only using one function, inline-javascript is kinda more enjoyable than this bunsh of code you need to "seperate Code from Design". It's a link which leads to a new page (print-dialog) - so it's okay for me (imo)

Comment: In the case of a single function on a single page then yeah maybe inline isn't the devil, but there are many reasons as to why you'd put your javascript in a separate file. Reuse, performance and maintenance being the biggest benefits (IMHO). While I get your point that for a single function why not inline it, but when/if that project grows and more javascript is needed its much harder/time consuming to refactor those function calls to a separate file.